# How to kill multiple threads in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I have created a UIButton and on click event, I am showing an image in the web view. Also, I am refreshing the image in every 30 sec. But when I click on button multiple times, refresh method get called multiple time as well. 
I want it to work like, It saves last click time and refreshes as per that time instead of multiple times.

What can I do for it?

I tried to kill all previous thread instead of the current thread but that's not working.

Please help if anyone already know the answer. 
Below is my image refresh code:

```
- (void)refreshBanner:(id)obj {
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        if (![SNRunTimeConfiguration sharedInstance].isInternetConnected) {
            [self removeBannerAdWithAdState:kADViewStateNotConnectedToInternet];
            return;
        }

        if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
            self.bannerPaused = YES;
            return;
        }

        self.adView.hidden = YES;

        UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
        topController = [SNADBannerView topViewControllerWithRootViewController:topController];
        if ([self checkInViewHierarchy:self parentView:topController.view]) {
            //        NSLog(@"Visible View Is: %@", self.adId);

            SNADMeta *meta = [[SNADDataBaseManager singletonInstance] adToShowWithBanner:YES excludeTyrooAd:YES audio:NO zoneId:self.adSoptZoneId fixedView:NO condition:nil contextualKeyword:nil onlyFromAJ:NO];
            SNADAdLocationType type = SNADAdLocationTypeHeader;
            if (self.bannerType == SmallViewTypeFooter) {
                type = SNADAdLocationTypeFooter;
            }

            if (self.isFromCustomEvent) {
                type = SNADAdLocationTypeAdMobBanner;
            }

            NSString *message = meta ? nil : kSNADOppMissReason_NoAdToShow;
            [SNRunTimeConfiguration fireOpportunityForAdLocation:type zoneId:self.adSoptZoneId reason:message];
            NSLog(@"******************* Opportuninty fired for refresh banner ***************************");

            if (meta) {
                self.meta = meta;
                [self updateContentForWebAd:nil];
                [self updateStatsForAd];

                //fireImpression
                [SNADBannerView fireImpression:self.meta];

                if ([meta.adSource isEqualToString:kSNADParameter_APC]) {
                    self.sdkMediation = [[SdkMediation alloc] init];
                    [self.sdkMediation fireTrackingAdType:self.meta.type isFill:YES];
                }

                // Ad Height Delegate.
                if ([self.meta.displayType isEqualToString:kSNADDisplayType_web]) {
                    self.adHeightDelegateCalled = YES;
                    NSInteger height = self.meta.height.integerValue;
                    self.bannerCH.constant = height;

                    if ([self.callBackDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(adWillPresentWithHeight:adId:adType:)]) {
                        [self.callBackDelegate adWillPresentWithHeight:height adId:self.adId adType:SeventynineAdTypeMainStream];
                    }
                }
            } else {
                [self removeBannerAdWithAdState:kADViewStateNoAdToShow];

                if ([meta.adSource isEqualToString:kSNADParameter_APC]) {
                    [self.sdkMediation fireTrackingAdType:self.meta.type isFill:NO];
                }

                return;
            }
        } else {
            //        NSLog(@"View Which Is Not Visible Now: %@", self.adId);
        }

        SNAdConfiguration *configuration = [SNAdConfiguration sharedInstance];
        [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:configuration.autoRefRate target:self selector:@selector(refreshBanner:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Use `NSOperationQueue ` or you can disable Button click when you click at first time and enable after loading First response

Comment: @Dhiru I can't disable button click as it's not in my control. I have implemented this feature in SDK. And UI thing is completely in developer's control who has integrated my SDK. And I have used NSOperationQueue and dispatch_sync as well but couldn't found desired result.

Comment: Can show little bit peace of code so that i can tell you more about this issue

Comment: Developer calls given API for showing banner ad:  **  [SNADViewManager showNativeOrBannerAdInView:self.view isBanner:YES priority:nil viewController:self options:nil targetCondition:nil]; ** After ad is displayed I refresh it in each 30 sec by given code below. I'm adding refresh method in my question. I m unable to send here.

Comment: is the button is outside of  `self.adView` or in side the `self.adView`  , i need to know more about scenario  to fix your issue 
please  send msg in chat...
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144892/ios-dev-expert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. 
Multiple threads created because a new view is created every time I call the API to display image. So now I am removing views if any available before displaying image, then only last object remains and refresh is called as per last called time.
Every View has it's own object that's why multiple threads has created.
By removing views my issue has been resolved.

Thanks everyone for replying.

Answer (score 0):

Use GCD, and not NSOperationQueue.

Then you step away from your immediate task. You do lots and lots of complicated things inside refreshBanner. And you will do more complicated things to make it work when the user taps multiple times.

Think about what exactly you need. Abstract the "refresh automatically, and when the button is clicked, but not too often" into a class. Then you create a class that takes a dispatch_block_t as an action, where a caller can trigger a refresh anytime they want, and the class takes care of doing it not too often. Then you create an instance of the class, set all the needed refresh actions as its action block, refreshBanner just triggers a refresh, and that class takes care of the details.

You do that once. When you've done it, you actually *learned* stuff and are a better programmer than before, and you can reuse it everywhere in your application, and in new applications that are coming.

Comment: What I need to do is, kill all threads running for same object except last one. My problem will be resolved. then only as per last call it'll refresh the image.

Answer (score 0):

`NSOperationQueue` have `cancelAllOperations` method. But for the main queue it's not a good decision to use this method, cause main queue is shared between different application components. You can accidentally cancel some iOS/other library operation together with your own.

So you can create `NSOperation` instances and store them in an array. Then you can call `cancel` for all scheduled operations by iterating trough this array, and it will only affect your operations.

Note that block operations doesn't support cancellation. You will need to create your own `NSOperation` subclass, extract code from your execution block into that subclass `main` method. Also, you'll need to add `[self isCancelled]` checks that will abort your logic execution at some points.

I forgot to mention that currently your execution block is fully performed on the main queue. So, you'll need to move any heavy-lifting to background thread if you want to cancel your operation in the middle of processing from main thread.

I need to add that I agree with @gnasher729 - this doesn't look like an optimal solution for the problem.